# Gradle build,ojdbc6-11.2.0.3

Tags: gradle

My demo has a Maven-Dependencies ,it contains an ojdbc6.jar.

I want to build a runnable jar with Gradle.
When i run:gradle build in command line.It works well,and create a Test.jar

In build/libs folder.when i run with:java -jar Test.jar. it shows：  Unable to load class: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriverclass not found.
Any one can help me out?Thanks a lot!

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Unable to load class: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver from ClassLoader:org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClass
>   ssLoader:org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$TcclSafeAggregatedClassLoader@60cbbfcd
>           at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:56)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:268)
>           ... 46 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
>           at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:230)
>           at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$TcclSafeAggregatedClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:456)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:38)

Comment: Could you provide the `build.gradle` file? And your project structure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have resolved it!

1. Download the ojdbc7.jar in F:\

> please visit oracle.com to download!

2. Run "cmd",then input below command:

> mvn install:install-file -Dfile=f:\ojdbc7.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle.weblogic -DartifactId=ojdbc7 -
>   Dversion=12.1.0.2.0 -Dpackaging=jar

3. If setup success,you will see ojdbc7 in the bellow path:

> C:\Users\Administrator.m2\repository\com\oracle\weblogic\ojdbc7\12.1.0.2.0

4. Here is my build.gradle:

       `buildscript {
       repositories {
           mavenCentral()
           maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-release" }
       }
       dependencies {
       classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-

        plugin:1.2.4.RELEASE")
       }
   }
   apply plugin: "java"
   apply plugin: "eclipse"
   apply plugin: "idea"
   apply plugin: "spring-boot"
   jar {
       baseName = "Test"
       version =  "0.1.0"
   }
   repositories {
       mavenCentral()
       mavenLocal();
       maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-release" }
   }
   dependencies {
       compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
       compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
       compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
       compile("org.springframework.flex:spring-flex-core:1.6.0.RC1")
       compile("com.oracle.weblogic:ojdbc7:12.1.0.2.0")
       testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
   }`

   task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
       gradleVersion = "2.4"
   }
   tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
       options.encoding = "UTF-8"
   }
5. The most important is add mavenLocal() to repositories